# How to assign ngTemplateOutput with a function return value?

Tags: angular

so I have the following code:

```
  <StackLayout formArrayName="products" *ngFor="let product of form.requestProduct.get('products')['controls']; let j=index">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="getTemplate(product.get('code'))">

    </ng-container>
  </StackLayout>
```

getTemplate() implementation:

```
  getTemplate(control: FormControl): string {
    return 'usernameTemplate';
  }
```

When I run this it throws an error:

> ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

Now how can I make the valueof ngTemplateOutlet dynamic based on the return value of a givent function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that simply returning the template name would do the job.
You also need to attach the template to a container.

So, here's my approach:

- add some `<ng-template>` in your view(**their order is important**)

```html
<!-- awesome-component.component.html -->
<div *ngFor="let p of products">
 <div (click)="changeProductTemplate(p)">{{ p?.name }}</div>
</div>

<ng-container #cont></ng-container>

<!-- The order is important! -->
<ng-template #code1 let-product>content2..</ng-template>
<ng-template #code2 let-product>content2..</ng-template>
<ng-template #code3 let-product>content2..</ng-template>
```

- get a reference to those templates by using `@ViewChildren`

```js
// awesome-component.component.ts
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>
@ViewChild('cont', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false}) cont: ViewContainerRef;
```

- every time you are selecting a product, one of those templates would be used, depending on `product code`.

```js
 // awesome-component.component.ts

 private templatesProductsMap = {
   code1: 1,
   code2: 2,
   code3: 3,
 };

 changeProductTemplate (product) {
   const tempIndex = this.getTemplateByProductCode(product.code);

   this.instantiateTemplate(tempIndex, { $implicit: product });
 }

 private getTemplateByProductCode (productCode) {
   return this.templatesProductsMap[productCode];
 }

 private instantiateTemplate (idx = 0, templateContext = {}) {
   this.cont.clear();

   const temp = this.templates.toArray()[idx];    
   this.cont.createEmbeddedView(temp, templateContext)

   this.cd.detectChanges();
 }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1rw6m2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is the implementation.

Comment: what is the value of cont here?

Comment: Its value will be the `ViewContainerRef`. Specifically, this: `<ng-container #cont></ng-container>`